# How to find all documents where the value of a field is null or empty

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to write a simple Mongo query to return all documents where the value of a field is null (or an empty array, I'm not sure what you call it).

Here is my query;

`db.getCollection('contact').find({'poco.name.email':false})`

Here is a screenshot of my collection using RoboMongo;

[image: screenshot of my collection using RoboMongo]

Ultimately, I need to transfer this to some PHP. So far I have this working;

```
$conditions = array_merge($conditions, [
  'owner.$id' => $this->getId(),
  'poco.name.familyName' => "Smith",
  //not sure what goes here.. something like
  //'poco.emails' => null,
]);

return Model_Mongo_Contact::getContacts($conditions, $sort, $fields, $limit, $skip);
```

That's probably going to be harder to answer without more access to the methods.. Or maybe not I am very new to Mongo it might be really obvious.

Comment: This documentation should be helpful : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: @Rajesh Whilst [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) is the correct thing to use here, there is a specific usage which will actually detect "both" an empty array as well as anything that is not an array or not present. Being `"poco.email.0": { "$exists": false }`, where you look for the `0` index position being present. As a `true` condition, the array is present and "not empty", so `false` naturally gives the reverse. That's what one answer given here explains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not PHP expert but I'll be doing in mongo shell as:

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {"poco.email":{$exists: true}}, 
    {"poco.email":{$ne: []}}
  ]})
```

Query above will list all documents where `poco.name.email` is not missing and is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept when looking for an "empty" array or even "non-existent" is to use a property of "dot notation" and search where the `0` index of the array does not exist. This can be achieved with using the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```
$conditions = array_merge($conditions, [
  'owner.$id' => $this->getId(),
  'poco.name.familyName' => "Smith",
  'poco.emails.0' => array( '$exists' => FALSE )
]);
```

That condition is true when either there is no property at all, or if it is something other than an array ( therefore no `"0"` field property ) or indeed an "empty" array ( since there is no content at the first index ).

This works best when the field is actually "indexed". So if in your "normal" structure you have "sub-documents" inside the array element with say a consistent field named `"address"` which is indexed as `"poco.emails.address"`, then you are best of pointing to that specific indexed property to see if it `$exists` or not:

```
$conditions = array_merge($conditions, [
  'owner.$id' => $this->getId(),
  'poco.name.familyName' => "Smith",
  'poco.emails.0.address' => array( '$exists' => FALSE )
]);
```

But if the array consists purely of "values" only and no "sub-documents", then simply testing for the `0` index position of the array as initially demonstrated will be enough.